# Firebase example about session cookies throwing errors

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, cookies, firebase-authentication

I am following an example from the firebase docs but I keep on getting errors. I have managed to solve most of them, but I get an error constantly saying that it can't find the `csrfToken` cookie.

I have tried different cookie libraries and checked in the browser but I still find no mention of a `csrfToken` cookie.

My code to submit (client side):

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($("#pEmail").val(), 
$("#pPass").val()).then(user => {
    // Get the user's ID token as it is needed to exchange for a session cookie.
    return firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
      // Session login endpoint is queried and the session cookie is set.
      // CSRF protection should be taken into account.
      // ...
      const csrfToken = Cookies.get('csrfToken');
      console.log(csrfToken);
      const postPromise = $.post("/signin", {idToken: idToken, csrfToken: csrfToken});
      return postPromise;
    });
  }).then(() => {
    // A page redirect would suffice as the persistence is set to NONE.
    return firebase.auth().signOut();
  }).then(() => {
    window.location.assign('/portal');
  });

});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the [Firebase node quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/blob/master/auth-sessions/app.js). Your node application should be setting this cookie. From the example code:

```
/**
 * Attaches a CSRF token to the request.
 * @param {string} url The URL to check.
 * @param {string} cookie The CSRF token name.
 * @param {string} value The CSRF token value to save.
 * @return {function} The middleware function to run.
 */
function attachCsrfToken(url, cookie, value) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url == url) {
      res.cookie(cookie, value);
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

Set up the middleware:

```
app.use(
    attachCsrfToken(
        '/', 
        'csrfToken', 
        (Math.random()* 100000000000000000).toString()
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a failure for verifySessionCookie, it returns an error because there is no session cookie set. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @LouisaScheinost I'd be happy to help you if I'm able to. Can you create a new question and post a link to it in a comment?